# Draw table using TikZ in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

What would be a minimal TikZ example to draw the following?

[image]

I am currently doing this with tables, but I would like to see how it can be done with TikZ.

Comment: have a look at the answer below with the `fit` library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \sf
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{bignode/.style={
                        minimum width=90pt,
                        minimum height=70pt,
                        draw}}
        \node[bignode] (S) {satisfiable};
        \node[bignode, anchor=west] at (S.east) (U) {unsatisfiable};
        \node[draw,below=15pt] at (S.center) (V) {valid};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: satisfiable]

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse (3 and 1);
  \draw (0,-1) -- (0,1);
  \node at (-1,0.5) {satisfiable};
  \node at (1.5,0) {unsatisfiable};
  \node[ellipse,draw] at (-2,-0.2) {valid};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}
    \sf
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] (S) {satisfiable};
        \node[right=0.3cm of S] (U) {unsatisfiable};
        \node[draw,below=0.2cm of S] (V) {valid};
        \node[draw, fit=(S)(U)(V)]{};
        \node[draw, fit=(S)(V)]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={minimum size=3cm, draw, font=\sffamily}, 
            column sep=-\pgflinewidth]
    {|[label={[draw, anchor=south, outer sep=2mm, minimum size=0mm]below:valid}]|satisfiable & unsatisfiable\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]